# Configurable products with same attribute_set not getting associated

Tags: magento, attributes, product, magmi, configurable

I have a question for you, Magento/Magmi Masters.
So after weeks of struggling setting everything up in Excel for Magento to digest my database correctly, I am stuck because of the configurable products. I input the same attribute_set for both simples and configurable product, though when I upload the csv, the products do show up in the list but don't get associated. So I go to the "Associated Products" section of the configurable product in the Admin panel and see NO products at all in the list. I click "Reset Filters" but nothing shows up either. I have tried random stuff but haven't come to a solution yet. If you guys could give me a hand with this I'd reeally appreciate it.
Thank you all in advance!
[See my CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpDmI.png)

Comment: What are your configurable attributes on a configurable product? Not sure how Magento handles import of configurable products.

Comment: Hi @MladenIlić , thanks for your comment. I'm using Magmi to try to ease the process. I have an attribute set (clothing) which contains 2 attributes (size, color). As you can see from my csv, I put "clothing" on both the simple products and the configurable products, in the attribute_set column. They show up fine in the catalog but don't show up as associated products within the config product...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's really hard to say from the csv what is wrong. Do your simple products have size properly set?

Comment: @MladenIlić Yes, I've checked that one. The thing which is odd to me is that if I reset the filters of the associated products, the list is empty although the simple products are in the catalog with the same attribute set as the configurable product!

Comment: Try creating one configurable product manually, and choose size attribute. Do you see associated products then?

Comment: @MladenIlić Great troubleshooting! If I create a configurable product manually and choose "clothing" as attribute set and ONLY "size" as attribute, I see them all! If I choose both "size" and "color", I see nothing! What does this mean? As you can see in my csv I put only "size" in each row. Thank you as always, man, great help.

Comment: Magmi is probably doing something wrong. You can check `catalog_product_super_attribute` to confirm this. Get the id of your configurable product and check to which attributes is it linked. No problem, really. :)

Comment: If I'm right, than this is an underlying bug in Magmi (could very well be), so there's no easy way to fix it.

Comment: @MladenIlić I have just checked and apparently it is n. 63 is linked to attribute 137 and 92 (see https://imgur.com/a/poGET ) . So it seems to me there are 2 duplicates for the only 2 configurable products I currently have, a working one (different attribute set) and a non-working one (n.63, the one we are talking about). Does it look wrong to you?